# Linux: What is the right way to configure the HOSTNAME directive in /etc/sysconfig/network?

Tags: centos6, linux-networking, hostname, fqdn

There's a (quiet) argument between me and my boss in regard to the right way to configure HOSTNAME directive in `/etc/sysconfig/network` file:

As far as I know, in the `HOSTNAME` directive you should specify the machine host name and not fully qualified domain name as my Boss says.

Why do I think that this is how it's supposed to be?

Because when you run:

```
hostname
```

The output should be your machine's host name and when you run:

```
hostname -f
```

The output should be hostname.dns.suffix

So in most servers in the production environment the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file is configured with `HOSTNAME=FQDN` and when you run `hostname` you get FQDN and I would like to change it to hostname rather than FQDN.

So now my boss wants a proof in regard to it but when I Google about it, I see in some sites that it's ok to set it as FQDN and in some it says that it must be only hostname.

In [CentOS official documentation site](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-network.html) they say it should be configured with FQDN but in [tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec93.html) they say it should be configured with just hostname.

So my question is, what is the right way to configure HOSTNAME in `/etc/sysconfig/network`?